# How do I fix loud fan noise and heat on my Sony Vaio?

Tags: ati, overheating, fan

I have Sony Vaio with AMD E2-2000 (1,75GHz) processor, 4GB RAM, and it runs Windows 8 as a default OS. After I installed Ubuntu 13.04, it worked but the fan sound got louder and the laptop would heat faster. What should I do to fix this problem?

I have tried looking for Ubuntu Netbook Edition but it seems its no more supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) for advanced power management. It can be configured and finetuned in many ways. By default, it is optimized mainly for good battery life when running on battery (which also means less heat and fan noise), but battery mode can be enabled manually or you can configure it how you want. Look at [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/285681/67920) for details how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem in a Vaio. In my case I have to switch off the main GPU and keep working only the integrated one in each system start. To do this run this command as root:

```
root@machine:~# echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Here you have the [reference Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).